# Center image vertically and horizontally with % width and height

Tags: html, css

how do i center a img with % width and height vertically and horizontally. The img is going to be responsive to the screen resolution and i need it to stay centered.

Comment: I have tried with position:absolute top:50% left:50% but you need fixed width for the img so you can add margin-left: half of the width; i have centered it with text-align:center but only horizontally

Comment: will your img size must fluid too? or fixed size?

Comment: fluid but i have managed to fix it. see the answer below. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by putting this img  in a table like this

```
<table align="center" valign="center">
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align:center;">
      <img style="width:80%;max-width:500px;" src="logo.png"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```